# Unable to reset minDate and maxDate in CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

I use this code to setup `CalendarView` for the first time and it works fine:

```
override fun setupCalendar(open: Boolean, minDate: Int, maxDate: Int) {
    calendar.minDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply { add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, minDate) }.timeInMillis
    calendar.maxDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply { add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, maxDate) }.timeInMillis
    calendar.visibility = getVisibility(open)
}
```

Then, depending on some user input, I use the same code with new values for min and max date to reset calendar's state. It seems like `CalendarView` takes new values, but the changes are not reflected on the calendar's layout.

So the question is how to reset `CalendarView`'s `minDate` and `maxDate` after they have been set once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invalidate the calendar view for changes to reflect.